# Перезагрузка страницы JS

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Помогите сделать скрипт, вернее там всего одна стрчока)))) которая бы перезагружал страницу на которой находится пользователь.
Это случайно не window.reload; ? Просто не работает что-то...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

location.href=location.href;

Answer (score 15):

```
location.reload() // window.location.reload()
```