# Отследить перезагрузку страницы

Tags: javascript

Как можно отследить перезагрузку страницы?
Просто нажатие f5 - это отловить событием keyup.
А как, к примеру, если нажмут на перезагрузку страницы в браузере (кнопка около строки url)?

```
 window.addEventListener('feydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 116)
    f5KeyDown = true;
 }

 window.addEventListener('beforeunload',function(e) {
    if(f5KeyDown) {
      сделать свою логику...
    }
 });
```

Или мб есть какой-нибудь параметр, который говорит, на какой роут происходит редирект? То есть, к примеру, если роут не меняется - значит перезагружают страницу.

Comment: Уверен, что можно дать хороший совет, только лучше скажите, что вы хотите сделать, если была перезагрузка страницы то что хотите сделать? вы хотите  отследить все перезагрузки страницы или только перезагрузка при каком-то условии?

Comment: Я хочу состояние страницы запомнить. То есть все флаги и тд. Но только при условии перезагрузки страницы (при закрытии вкладки, или перехода на раздел - тут не сохранять). Сохранить думал банально - в sessionStorage.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunload ?

Comment: Может вам эта тема поможет - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/79373/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-js

Comment: [Check if page gets reloaded or refreshed in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004978/check-if-page-gets-reloaded-or-refreshed-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант делать запись при в сессию при перезагрузке страницы и отталкиваться уже от неё.

```
var Reloaded  = function(){
    Тут Ваш код по запоминанию флагов страницы и так далее.
} //страницу перезагрузили

window.onload = function() {
  var loaded = sessionStorage.getItem('loaded');
  if(loaded) {
    Reloaded();
  } else {
    sessionStorage.setItem('loaded', true);
  }
}
```

Comment: sessionStorage же хранит до того момента, пока браузер не перезагрузили. Я к тому, что если вдруг закроют вкладку, потом откроют заново страницу, то ваш код сработает, тк время жизни sessionStorage будет актуально.

Comment: @bruce Не сработает. Объект sessionStorage хранит данные ограниченное время, они удаляются сразу после того как пользователь завершает свой сеанс или закрывает браузер. В Вашем случае, если пользователь покинул страницу, сессия заканчивается. Это же не localstorage или cookie